# How do I get server response code in WebView2

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, httpresponse, webview2

I am trying to use WebView2 and get the server response code. However CoreWebView2WebResourceRequestedEventArgs.Response is always null for some reason:

```
    webView.CoreWebView2Ready += CoreWebView2Ready;        

    private void CoreWebView2Ready(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webView.CoreWebView2.AddWebResourceRequestedFilter("*", CoreWebView2WebResourceContext.All);
        webView.CoreWebView2.WebResourceRequested += WebResourceRequested;
    }

    private void WebResourceRequested(object sender, CoreWebView2WebResourceRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        /* e.Response is always null for some reason */
        if (e.Response != null)
        {
            int statusCode = e.Response.StatusCode;
            string header = e.Response.Headers.GetHeader("myheader");
        }
    }
```

How do I get the response code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `e.Response` will always be `null` because the `WebResourceRequested` event is triggered before the request is sent. You're supposed to create a response in the eventhandler. That is not what you want.

So what do you do? Well, the new **pre-release** version of `WebView2` might have, what you want - a `WebResourceResponseReceived` event. This is triggered when you receive a response from the server and here the `e.Response` will be available.

**To use it:**

1. Install/update `Microsoft.WebView2` **pre-release version** (latest).
2. Install the **Canary** build of Microsoft Edge.
3. **Uninstall** the WebView2 Runtime - otherwise that will still be used.

Now you can use code like below (note the new event names):

```
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void WebView21_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            webView21.CoreWebView2.WebResourceResponseReceived += CoreWebView2_WebResourceResponseReceived;
        }

        private void CoreWebView2_WebResourceResponseReceived(object sender, CoreWebView2WebResourceResponseReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Response != null && e.Response.Headers.Contains("date"))
            {
                int statusCode = e.Response.StatusCode;
                string header = e.Response.Headers.GetHeader("date");
                MessageBox.Show(header);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `e.Response.Headers.GetHeader` will throw an exception if the header doesn't exist, so check it first.

Comment: YIkes, this is not not too friendly to developers. Simply getting the HTTP response code shouldn't require examining all the headers!

Comment: @O'Rooney: Getting the header is just an example, not required.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I misread it.

Comment: I wonder how one should figure out which of the main possible web resource results should be taken as the final result for your page navigation, and how to coordinate the timing of these events vs the NavigationCompleted event on WebView2...

Comment: Yeah, I read some docs and there is one of these response received events for every URI that might be accessed including redirects, images, scripts and so on. Most of these are irrelevant, but I'm not sure how one would tell which one is the relevant one.

Comment: @O'Rooney: `e.Request.Uri` should give you the url sent to the server.

Comment: See my answer below, there is now a simple way to get the http status code for the overall request

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the WV2 SDK released yesterday (1.0.1293.44) adds a new interface that will give us exactly the thing we need:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/icorewebview2navigationcompletedeventargs2?view=webview2-1.0.1293.44

```
interface ICoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs2 : 
public ICoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs

get_HttpStatusCode  The HTTP status code of the navigation if it involved an HTTP request.
```